# Using backstage

Tags: docker, devops, backstage

I'd like to attempt to start using Spotify's Backstage at my job, but, I'm a bit clueless on how to start exactly...

I currently want to use it for two main tasks we have in our infrastructure - I want to add documentation to the Backstage platform, it can be even handwritten markdown files that will get centralized there - seems like it supports MkDocs so this should be doable...

Then, I want to embed in the Backstage platform a custom script/docker image we use to create DB replicas for local development.

Essentially, I want to start unifying in a central location some of our infrastructure and documentation concerns which I think is exactly what Backstage aims to solve.

I've managed to download and start the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/backstage-cookiecutter). But, any more practical hands-on tutorials on how to embed and run custom docker images from the platform together with some docs?

Answer (score 0):

Backstage is not an application, it is a framework. It provides a way to create a starter application that contains the software catalog plugin, the documentation plugin and the scaffolder (a component that can be used to create applications based on templates) with a small demo template but that's basically all you get out of the box.

For more features you have to add plugins and configure them. There are 200+ free [plugins](https://backstage.io/plugins) available and also several dozens that Spotify provides by subscription.

Adding a plugin requires writing several lines of code in the application and, usually, several lines in the configuration YAML file. The documentation of each plugin describes these changes in detail.

The Backstage documentation explains the concepts and [how to start](https://backstage.io/docs/getting-started/)  building your application. If the existing plugins do not satisfy your needs, you can write your own plugins. Backstage documentation provides information about [how to write a plugin](https://backstage.io/docs/plugins/create-a-plugin). JavaScript/TypeScript and React knowledge is required.